# automatically hit submit button after a time period

Tags: javascript, php

I know how to submit a form after a time period. But it seems to not work for a submit button. I have a quiz that pulls the questions from a database and has a submit button. I want it to hit the submit button after a few hours and go to another page telling the user that it has been submitted.

```
function changeSncro(){
sncro = 1;
return confirm('You are about to close this attempt. Once you close the attempt you will no longer be able to change your answers.')
}


window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    if(sncro !=1){
        var message = 'If you leave prior to SUBMITTING your test, it WILL NOT be scored and you WILL NOT get another attempt';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt ) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
        }
            return message;
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout('document.test.submit()',5000);
</script>
<input name="test" value="Submit and finish" onclick="return changeSncro()">
```

Comment: Can you share with us the method that you already know? Maybe someone can point out why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, I highly recommend you read this before you get down voted http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask **Relevant source code** is important to us. We debug `your code`, not type it out for you. *Share any attempts or research*

Comment: Thanks. I've edited above.

Comment: Where is the form you want to submit? Also i'm pretty sure `5000` = 5 seconds not a few hours...

Comment: What is the difference between your non-working code and working code? Was the timeout length the only thing you changed, or did you use a different method, like simulating a button click?

Comment: " after a few hours" you expect the user to still be on the same page with the browser open having not them self submitted?

Comment: Yes, like simulating a button click after 2 hours (I know 5000 isn't enough time,it's only for testing)

Comment: no one is going to be sitting on the page for two hours

Comment: @54696d where is the form or input/data you want to submit? If you have nothing to submit then it removes the point of submitting.... Give us something to work with.... With what you have on display is saying "I want to submit nothing every 5 seconds"

Comment: @Dagon Yes, that's way i'm adding this feature. Some are just keeping it open. I want it to submit the answered questions (if any).

Comment: You button has two names. Moveover, you cannot submit a submit button. Buttons are clicked, forms are submitted.

Comment: I made some more edits. Sorry, thought this would be simpler.

Comment: The key to getting help is posting relevant source code. I see you have updated you post but this still doesn't have a form to submit and the existing javascript appears to have errors. `sncro` will be undefined and you have a script tag inside your javascript. When you say you want to **submit** do you mean you want to call the changeSncro() function?

Comment: Why not use localStorage and post through code on unload?  or cookies if you want..  new FormData('your form') -> ajax post.  Something like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has several problems:

```
setTimeout('document.test.submit()',5000);
```

I'll walk through some steps to make it better.

setTimeout generally should be called with a function rather than a string as it's first parameter. Having it as a string is causing the browser to run eval on the string, which can be really bad. In this case it won't really matter, but I'd change it anyway to make it "better code". Improved version:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.test.submit();
}, 5000);
```

Moreover you should probably not use `document.test`. The best practice is to use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById` if you need to support very old browsers.

If it's really the button you want to click (and not just submit the form), you could use

```
document.querySelector('[name="test"]').click();
```

in order to make it a lot more clear what you are clicking.

Even better would probably be to submit the form instead of clicking the button (which probably is what the button does anyway). If this is the case, you would give the form an id or something else that is selectable and:

```
document.querySelector('#myForm').submit();
```

*As mentioned in the comments, there are other problems as well, but I'd think that's just from copying the code to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing enough information so i'm going to answer the best I can with the limited information.

> You don't have a `form` to submit so i'm going to assume by `submit` you want to trigger/fire the **changeSncro()** function just like the onclick event you have in place.

```
setTimeout(changeSncro,5000);
```

---

--------------------**Demo**--------------------

---

```js
function changeSncro(){
 alert("Function called!");
}

setTimeout(changeSncro,5000);
```

```html
<p>Wait 5 seconds for function to call....</p>
<button onclick="changeSncro()">changeSncro</button>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help as well. I've pasted what I was trying to do and it's working now.

Comment: You are very welcome. Tip for next time you need help: Submit **all** relevant source code, you will get help/answers much quicker!

Answer (score 0):

@Ineentho You are awesome! I was trying to keep it simple because I have a lot of other code. But here is what (basically) I'm trying to do and it works now

```
<script>    
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('[name="test"]').click();
}, 5000);
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p>
        <button name="test" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Glad to help! Now that you have an ID tag you could use `getElementById('submit')` or `querySelector('#submit')` to make the code a little bit simpler, but good to see it working. A tip on using Stack Overflow in general: You should probably have posted this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Do you think there would be an issue if the timeout was set to 14400000?

Comment: Nah, that would probably work just fine. I'd recommend specifying it as `(1000 * 3600 * 4)` instead though to make it more readable. Welcome to SO btw :)